# R equivalent to Stata's xtregar

Tags: r, stata

I'm doing a replication of an estimation done with Stata's `xtregar` command, but I'm using R instead.

The `xtregar` command implements the method from Baltagi and Wu (1999) "Unequally spaced panel data regressions with AR(1) disturbances" paper. As Stata describes it:

> xtregar fits cross-sectional time-series regression models when the disturbance term is first-order autoregressive.  xtregar offers a within estimator for fixed-effects models and a GLS estimator for random-effects models.  xtregar can accommodate unbalanced panels whose observations are unequally spaced over time.

So far, for the fixed-effects model, I used the `plm` package for R. The attempt looks like this:

```
plm(data=A, y ~ x1 + x2, effect = "twoways", model = "within")
```

Nevertheless is not complete (comparing to `xtregar` description) and the results are not quite like the ones Stata provides. Furthermore, Stata's command needs to set a panel variable and a time variable, feature that's (as far as I can tell) absent in the `plm` environment.

Should I settle with `plm` or is there another way of doing this?

PS: I searched thoroughly different websites but failed to find a equivalent to Stata's `xtregar`.

**Update**

After reading Croissant and Millo (2008) "Panel Data Econometrics in R: The `plm` Package", specifically seccion 7.4 "Some useful 'econometric' models in `nlme`" I used something like this for the Random Effects part of the estimation:

```
gls(data=A, y ~ x1 + x2, correlation = corAR1(0, form = ~ year | pays), na.action = na.exclude)
```

Nevertheless the following has results closer to those of Stata

```
lme(data=A, y ~ x1 + x2, random = ~ 1 | pays, correlation = corAR1(0, form = ~ year | pays), na.action = na.exclude)
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and the result you expect (i.e., the result of Stata commant)?

Comment: By the way, you can set the panel variable and time variable by `index` argument!  It is in the example section of `?plm`.

Comment: @KotaMori thanks for your comments! I completely missed the index option, I'll look into it! As for the sample and result I'll edit the question to add that

Comment: I'm also looking for this and I don't find it in the plm documentation. Your code in any case simply estimates a model with individual specific intercepts and time dummies (by the way, plm is bad at that! Very slow and quickly out of memory!). Maybe this helps: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6469/simple-linear-model-with-autocorrelated-errors-in-r as pglm exists as well

Comment: @PeterPan thanks for your comment. I updated the question with the latest code I used, with the `nlme` package, with gives something similar to Stata's RE with `xtregar`. Perhaps the Baltagi and Wu method hasn't been implemented yet ir R as such.

Comment: This is more a CrossValidated question imho...

Answer (score 2):

Try `{panelAR}`. This is a package for regressions in panel data that addresses AR1 type of autocorrelations.
Unfortunately, I do not own Stata, so I can not test which correlation method to replicate in `panelCorrMethod`

```
library(panelAR)

model <- 
  panelAR(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, 
    data = A, 
    panelVar  = 'pays', 
    timeVar   = 'year', 
    autoCorr  = 'ar1', 
    rho.na    = TRUE, 
    bound.rho = TRUE, 
    panelCorrMethod ='phet' # You might need to change this parameter. 'phet' uses the HW Sandwich stimator for heteroskedasticity cases, but others are available.
    )
```