# Is there an R function for Fixed Effect AR(1) Disturbances?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, plm

I'm trying to do a Fixed Effect analysis with AR(1) Disturbances.
From research, I found that there was a package called panelAR that incorporated the fixed effect analysis with autoregression disturbances, but the package was removed last year.
Is there a way to conduct the analysis in R?

Accordingly, STATA has a function called xtregar, but I am more comfortable using R so, wish to try with R.

I tried the following code but it says the package does not exist anymore.

```
pdata20032020_2 <- panelAR(RDItplusone ~
                         PBA
                       +PAA
                       #+CASH
                       #+COMMON_SHARES_OUTSTANDING
                       +SIC_CODE
                       +MS
                       +HHI
                       +AbsorbedSlack
                       +UnabsorbedSlack
                       +PotentialSlack
                       #+SchumacherSlack_Bromiley
                       #+CURRENT_LIABILITIESTOTAL
                       #+CURRENT_RATIO
                       #+MARKET_VALUE
                       #+NET_INCOME_DOLLAR
                       +NET_SALES_OR_REVENUES
                       #+QUICK_RATIO
                       #+SHORTTERM_INVESTMENTS
                       +TOTAL_ASSETS
                       #+CEO_TOTAL_WRDS
                       #+Analyst_TOTAL_WRDS
                       #+Analyst_CCC_standardized_avg
                       , data=pdata20032020
                       ,timeVar = 'year'
                       ,panelVar = 'company'
                       ,autoCorr = c("ar1","none", "psar1")
                       ,panelCorrMethod = c("none","phet","pcse","pwls", "parks")
                       , rhotype ="breg"
                       , bound.rho = FALSE
                       , rho.na.rm = FALSE
                       , panel.weight = c("t-1", "t")
                       , dof.correction = FALSE
                       , complete.case = FALSE
                       , seq.times = FALSE
                       , singular.ok=TRUE)
```

Comment: When looking for packages that are not available from CRAN, a good idea is to check if they are on github. Seems to be true in this case: https://github.com/kkashin/panelAR This should get you the package: `devtools::install.github("kkashin/panelAR")` Be aware that the package was made for R 2.15, so has not been updated in a while, which may be the reason why it is not on CRAN any more.

Comment: Or by installing package panelAR from CRAN's archive, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71664861/r-package-panelar-not-available-to-install

Comment: You may look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585090/r-equivalent-to-statas-xtregar